# Father and son - Hagbah and Gelilah, Pesicha for two Torahs

Tags: torah-reading, torah-service, family-members, superstition, ayin-hara-evil-eye

The Shulchan Aruch 141:6 writes that from a halachic standpoint a father and son may have aliyos back-to-back, however due to the worry of ayin harah we don't allow it. The Misnah Brurah and Be'er Heitiv explain different scenarios where back-to-back aliyos would be allowed. In a case of two Sifrei Torah would be one allowed, or if they were called up already (yamod was said).

My question is what about hagbah and gelilah and pesicha for two sifrei Torah, these two cases don't involve aliyos, nor testimony  (believe the Bais Yosef gives this reason for no back-to-back), so would it be prohibited? I have seen gabbaim being makpid on these, but not sure where they got this idea from, is there a source for both of these cases?

Comment: What about pesicha and Rishon? Hagbah/Gelilah on Sefer Rishon and Shvi'i or Maftir from Sefer Sheini?

Answer (score 4):

[Shaalos U'Teshuvos Avnei Chaifetz 16:3](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=665&pgnum=33) says that so long as they are not called up by name there is no issue of Ayin Hara and it is permitted.

[Shaalos U'Teshuvos Mishne Halachos 3:20](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1875&st=&pgnum=43) says it is not recommended.