# Limitations on two brothers or father and son one after the other, other than torah service?

Tags: halacha, minhag, torah-service, ayin-hara-evil-eye

Shulchan Aruch Orach Chaim 141:6 rules

> יכולים לקרות שני אחים זה אחר זה, והבן אחר האב, ואין מניחים אלא בשביל עין הרע
>
> It is possible to call up to read the Torah two brothers, one after the other, likewise a son after a father. However we don't let them do it because of ayin hara

The Beis Yosef explains that although we don't rule like the Orchos Chaim who prohibits this meikkar hadin, the halacha is like the Kol Bo and the Mordechai that we don't permit this because of ayin hara.

I'm curious if this ruling applies in any other context. For example, by Sheva brachos, or is it only applicable to areas where a person's full name is mentioned (as is the custom when someone is called up to the Torah), where it is more noticeable that they're related.

I'm not asking if ayin hara is something to be concerned about I'm asking that assuming this halacha stands, is it specific to the Torah reading.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by Sheva Berakhot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Father and son - Hagbah and Gelilah, Pesicha for two Torahs](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/79547/father-and-son-hagbah-and-gelilah-pesicha-for-two-torahs)

Comment: @DoubleAA, disingenuity doesn't become you. I'm pretty sure you know what he means, even if [the widespread practice he's referring to is not original](/a/66606).

Comment: @sabbahillel An answer to that won't necessarily answer this. Even if the answer there is assur, this asked for *all* cases where we invoke this Halacha. That question wouldn't address Sheva Brachos, for instance. Even if that is assur, that doesn't mean it always is. My reading of [this](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3507/closing-as-duplicate-of-broader-post) seems to indicate that since a complete answer to that post won't necessarily address this one, it would be fine. If anything, it should be the other way around!

Comment: I agree with @DonielF

Answer (score 3):

The sefer Nisuin KeHilchesa pg. 299 quotes in the name of Rav Elyashiv that two brothers, or a father and son, may recite sheva brachos in sequence, and one need not worry for ayin hara. So at the very least this concern doesn't apply to this case, although I don't know the difference why here no and there yes.

Comment: It's hard to learn much from this since in any case where there was sufficient likelihood of familial strife that we'd permit splitting up the seven blessings among different relatives we'd also seemingly have sufficient concern to push off any Ayin Hara "issues" as well.